# How to determine to what hosts Android apps are connecting (root)?

Tags: root-access, data-monitoring, hosts

How does one determine to what hosts Android apps are connecting (or trying to connect)?

Want to know this information even if the host is being blocked by an entry in the `hosts` file.

Assume the device has root privileges.

Comment: You might want to see: [Check which IPs or web-sites an app is communicating with?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/32953/16575) // [Listen which URLs an app tries to connect](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43444/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend "Charles Proxy" for Windows.

It acts like a SSL MITM proxy, you set it's IP/PORT on your Phone and most of the traffic gets redirected/dissected.